# ASP.NET JavaScript slash symbol escaping

Tags: javascript, asp.net, string, escaping, innerhtml

I'm working on ASP.NET project. And there is a one issue, which doesn't allow me to make a good webpage view.

There is a piece of code:

```
alertPanel.innerHTML = "some text<br />";
```

When I've have run such code, my webpage didn't render the `<br />` tag.

I tried to looked at the debugger and have seen, that it goes without a `/` symbol:
[image]

I've searched info in web and read, that this symbol could be escaping and it was ofered to use, the next syntax:

```
alertPanel.innerHTML = 'some text<br "/>';
```

But when I dit it and tried to look at the final result, it was:

[image]

See? It does make a string `?=""` where I didn't make such a code.

Also, I've tried to do with `\/` escaping:

[image]

No success.

I have also tried to do with the `.value` option:

```
document.getElementById("alertPanel").value = "new text value";
```

But, no success.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: I can promise Javascript is not at fault here :-)

Comment: The `<br>` should render the same with or without the trailing slash. The slash is only significant for XHTML (pretty much dead), not HTML. Also, it's not a good style to use `<br>`s anyways.

Comment: @JanDvorak why is to use `<br>` a bad idea? Or you refers only to `xhtml` stuff?

Comment: Without the rest of the HTML (and maybe the CSS), it's impossible to tell why the br isn't "rendered". BTW this doesn't seem to be a JavaScript problem, as Jan said, but just an HTML/CSS one.

Comment: @GeloVolro Ending the HTML of an element by a br isn't good practice. You should use CSS instead for your bottom padding.

Comment: The problem with `br`s is that they only introduce a line break. No height, no margins, [no styling possible](http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/4C4Fm/). It's better to use block-level elements (say, `<p>`) to separate content. The other reason is that they are presentational tags: They represent how the document should display, not what data it contains. The goal is to avoid presentational markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use escape character?

Use this

```
alertPanel.innerHTML = "some text<br \/>";
```

Comment: it doesn't help me, I've updated the question body with your suggestion and posted screenshot with showing the final result

Comment: please check again the rendered html and provide the relevant code.
Also see this http://forums.asp.net/t/1332305.aspx/1